# Future of web apps vs desktop apps

Tags: web-applications, cloud, desktop-application

I tried searching the stackoverflow database for a question similar to mine, but I was not satisfied with what I found, so here is my question. What do you think the future of web applications will be compared to desktop applications or vice versa?

I am thinking of writing a desktop application in the future. I've never been a fan of web development, but that's just fine because everyone will have different opions of, tendencies towards the computer world. Now, considering that it's wise to invest towards the future rather than in the present, I want to know if web apps will be more popular than desktop apps or vice versa. What is your vision for the future of cloud and native development strategies?

Comment: The reason you did not find any 'satisfying' answers to this question on Stack Overflow is because this is not a site for such questions. It is entirely subjective (unless you believe people can tell the future)

Comment: i've seen a lot of subjective questions on stackoverflow. is there a different website for such questions now?

Comment: Probably programming.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

[sigh] People keep saying 'web app' vs. 'desktop app', and no one has a good set of criteria that would define one or the other.

Using "web" technologies - HTML, CSS, JS, one can develop an application that is packaged and deployed to the user's computer using one of the traditional "desktop" deployment technologies - ZIP, MSI. Such application could benefit from "desktop" technologies like offline storage, but still authenticate against a third party server using OAuth, OpenID, or a plain user/pass combo. Is such an app a "web" or a "desktop" app?

Comment: I started to put together a short, smart-alecky response to this that declared the app to be a Desktop app, and explained why. But when I also tried to explain why a Web app would conversely be called a web app, I realized that by the seemingly obvious standards I'd used, most web apps would be in danger of being called desktop apps too. Then again, I'm typing this right now in firefox on my notebook... which is on my LAP... so SO is clearly a Laptop app!!

Comment: @Andrew Barber - I am curious what were the "seemingly obvious standards" you started with? :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I remember anymore, really. But it was a simplistic and legalistic standard which, like most simplistic and legalistic standards, can be inaccurate to the point of comedy in real life.

Answer (score 1):

I venture a guess: The users don't care much, as long as the result is close to what they want.

(Heck, most users don't even know what OS their computer runs.)

Since user demand shapes the market, all sorts of software will stay with us - the technology used is just means to an end.